# Regarding SIGTSTP error and unending input

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14, c++17

The below code gives SIGTSTP but I am not able to find the fault. The original question link is: https://codeforces.com/contest/102/problem/B  . Please Help.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;

  int main()
  {
    int x,sum=0,count=0;
    string s; cin>>s;


    while(s.length()>1){

      for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        x=s[i]-'0';
        sum+=x;
      }
      s=std::to_string(sum);
      count++;
    }


    cout<<count;      
    return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but please read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend that you learn how to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I applied a hell lot of print statements but none of them helped:(

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>
 using namespace std;` - No. Just *no*. Don't *ever* do that.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/5910058)

Comment: @tempmail102 You are supposed to run the program in a *debugger* on your own machine. A debugger like `gdb` allows you to step through your program line by line and see what exactly it does. Using print statements is a very poor method of debugging in many cases.

Comment: You forgot to reset the variable sum to 0 at the beginning of each while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say the input is `19`.

The first iteration of the outer loop will make `sum` equal to `10`, and sets `s` to `"10"`.

The second iteration of the outer loop (when `s` is `"10"`) will *add* `1` (and `0`) to `sum`, making it equal to `11`, so when the inner loops end then `s` becomes `"11"`.

The third iteration of the outer loop will add `2` (`1` and `1`) to `sum`, so `sum` becomes `13` and `s` becomes `"13"`.

And so on forever.

The length of `s` will *never* become equal to (or smaller than) `1`. And that leads to an infinite loop. Which will likely be stopped by the online system due to a timeout.

I haven't read the problem description (in the future please include it in the question, to make your questions self-contained) but your algorithm is wrong, and you need to rethink your solution. Very likely you should reset `sum` (i.e. `sum = 0;`) before the inner loop, or better yet *define* it inside the inner loop:

```
int x,count=0;
string s; cin>>s;

while(s.length()>1){
  int sum = 0;

  for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
    x=s[i]-'0';
    sum+=x;
  }
  s=std::to_string(sum);
  count++;
}
```

<sub>[I reasoned me to this by doing [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of the code]</sub>